# How to redirect all requests for localhost:483 to localhost:80 with dnsmasq

Tags: linux, apache-httpd, firefox, dnsmasq, https

I have an issue with redirecting advertising domains to localhost on Linux Mint. I've followed the instructions on [Debain Administration Guide](https://debian-administration.org/article/535/Blocking_ad_servers_with_dnsmasq) and [this gist on dns-based ad-blocking](https://gist.github.com/OnlyInAmerica/75e200886e02e7562fa1).

Generation of hosts file and redirecting works, I've also installed a local web server for catching requests.

However, instead of having empty places in a web browser sometimes I get notifications that establishing connection was impossible. This happened because I don't have HTTPS server only HTTP. So I've prepared self-signed certificate and reconfigured apache adequately. Again everything works, but in Firefox I'm getting notifications that my server is untrusted.

I would like to get rid of those notifications, so I'm wondering if there is a possibility to set in Firefox a security exception for domains redirected to `127.0.0.1` or to redirect `127.0.0.1:483` to `127.0.0.1:80` with `dnsmasq`?